# Stumped by Run Time error '1004': Unable to set the X property of the PageSetup class

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a sub for the page setup of a sheet. It used to work earlier on different computers.

But for a unknown reason now I get an error message pops up for Y.PageSetup.X = ... :
Run time error 1004 unable to set the X property of the pagesetup class, where X includes all used properties.
And Y is variable of type worksheet.

I looked into this error on Microsoft support, it says "This problem occurs when there are no printer drivers installed on your computer. Excel cannot set or get page setup properties if no printer drivers are installed."

Here is my code:

```
Dim oSheet As Worksheet
Dim oDescription As Worksheet

Range(oSheet.Cells(1, 1), oSheet.Cells(1, zIdxMediaContents)).Font.Name = "Calibri"
    Range(oSheet.Cells(1, 1), oSheet.Cells(1, zIdxMediaContents)).Orientation = 45
    Range(oSheet.Cells(1, 1), oSheet.Cells(1, zIdxMediaContents)).HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignLeft
    Range(oSheet.Cells(1, 1), oSheet.Cells(1, zIdxMediaContents)).Font.Size = 6
    Range(oSheet.Cells(1, 1), oSheet.Cells(1, zIdxMediaContents)).Font.Color = 0
    Range(oSheet.Cells(1, 1), oSheet.Cells(1, zIdxMediaContents)).Font.Bold = True
    Range(oSheet.Cells(1, 1), oSheet.Cells(1, zIdxMediaContents + 1)).VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignBottom
    
    Range(oSheet.Cells(1, 1), oSheet.Cells(2, zIdxMediaContents + 1)).Interior.Color = &HFFFFFF
    Range(oSheet.Cells(2, 1), oSheet.Cells(2, zIdxMediaContents + 1)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
    
    oSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&""Calibri"" &B&6 " & cHeaderColour & cHeaderText 
    oSheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "&""Calibri"" &6 " & "J.nr.:" & tJournal
    oSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "&""Calibri"" &6 " & Format(Now, "d. mmmm yyyy")
        oDescription.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&""Calibri"" &B&6 " & cHeaderColour & cHeaderText
        oDescription.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "&""Calibri"" &6 " & "J.nr.:" & tJournal
        oDescription.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "&""Calibri"" &6 " & Format(Now, "d. mmmm yyyy")
```

Comment: So the obvious question is do you have a default printer set up?

Comment: Yes I have, as I wrote the program use to work earlier on the same computer and other computers as well!

Comment: Actually, you said it used to work on *different* computers, hence the question. ;) Have you tested actually printing the workbook/sheet?

Comment: Sorry :-), No I have not tried to print the workbook/sheet. I think I need to explain a bit more about what realy the  program does: The input data to the program is a XML database consisting of thousands of xml files, .asb files, .cap, .asf files etc., the program make a list out of the onput data in PDF format, where the different types of data is represented on each row with a link to the actual data such as an image. This pageformating is regarded to the PDF output file. Så neither the input nor the output is a workbook/sheet.

Comment: You're populating a worksheet though. If you can't print that, that is why the code is failing. I've only ever seen that error related to a printer issue - usually because there isn't a default one installed for whatever account is running the code.

Comment: Thanks Rory, the problem was actually a network printer problem, NOT in my vba code. But I did not think about it, since the prionter was working always. IT admin has confirmed that tere is problem with the network printer and they are solving it :-)